# Last.fm playlist to Spotify playlist

Tags: spotify, last.fm, spotify-playlist

Is there any easy way to convert a Last.fm playlist, such as [this one](http://www.last.fm/user/afrodisiax/library/playlists/4a86x_situation_intellectuelle), to a Spotify playlist? (One which would include, of course, those of the songs that are available on Spotify.)

You can export playlists from Last.fm as [XSPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Shareable_Playlist_Format), but Spotify doesn't seem to directly support XSPF imports.

Comment: I created a feature request for this for Spotify. You can track and vote for it at http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Support-importing-XML-Shareable-Playlist-Format-XSPF-used-by/idi-p/88641.

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but [this website](http://spotibot.com/playlist/#lastfm) lets you create Spotify playlists based on loved tracks and recommendations. Maybe you can contact the guy who made it can adapt it if you contact him.

**Edit**: Actually you can use [**Playlistify**](http://playlistify.org/) to import XSPF playlists into Spotify.

Comment: Yes, not exactly what I asked for, but +1 because this service is pretty cool too!

Comment: Nice, Playlistify solves this! (Although it's not quite as straightforward as it could be.) Check out the [Situation intellectuelle](http://dir.playlistify.org/3665/Situation-Intellectuelle.html) playlist, baked from the last.fm example I mentioned (157 of 200 tracks found). To listen, click "open in spotify" and paste in Spotify.

Comment: Playlistify is no longer available. I cannot get the website to load. Are there any other options for converting XSPF files to Spotify playlists?